# Apply n-series of dplyr verbs

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to apply a series of `dplyr-verbs`; and for my example specifically, I am interested in `mutate`. Essentially, I want to produce an output that would look like this:

```
mtcars %>% mutate(x1=1) %>% mutate(x2=2) %>% mutate(x3=3) ...
```

Essentially, I have tried:

```
anotherTest <- function(data,...){
  cols = list(...)
  testFunc <- function(more){
    return(mutate(x = more))
  }
  n <- length(cols)
  addMutation <- replicate(n, testFunc)
  test <- {{data}} %>% lapply(addMutation, function(x){ x(cols)})
  return(test)
}
anotherTest(mtcars, 1)
```

But this produces the following error:

> Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
> object 'addMutation' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: replace `{{data}}` (not in a verb) with `data` (no braces) as a start, though there are other issues here

Comment: I think your `lapply` might need to be a `Reduce` (or `for`-loop).

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the feedback, I used `n` within `replicate`, this is defined by the number of additional arguments. I have tried `Reduce`, but the `addMutation` is a list of functions, so getting it to perform like the expected output above is rather tricky, because most functions like `Reduce`, or `map`, require a `.f` for the transformation.

Comment: This is likely simpler in base R, is there a reason you need to do it in `dplyr`?

Comment: Can you provide some more context about why you're approaching it this way? The example is straightforward enough that base R would be a super easy way to add these, and if you still wanted to be able to have it as part of a pipe you could simply wrap all the base R functions in a larger function.

Comment: @AaronleftStackOverflow I am working on another function that needs to apply `dplyr` verbs like `mutate` over and over again on the same dataset. This has to come after a `pipe` operator. This is a test example

Comment: Ok, still not seeing it. Why does the "over and over again" part need to use dplyr?

Comment: @AaronleftStackOverflow The update should be more revealing as to why it has to repeat over and over again.

Comment: Looks like you added more info, but then reverted to the original; was that intended?

Comment: Although we can't tell you what you're really going for, I wonder if you're trying to reimplement `across`...

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Cut down mtcars to make the output shorter.   Now, `mutate` can take a data.frame as an argument so create a one row data.frame with the desired names and values and pass it to `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 3
mtcars %>%
  select(1:4) %>%
  head(4) %>%
  mutate(setNames(data.frame(as.list(1:n)), tolower(make.names(1:n))))
```

giving:

```
                mpg cyl disp  hp x1 x2 x3
Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110  1  2  3
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110  1  2  3
Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93  1  2  3
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110  1  2  3
```

**2)** cbind mtcars and a list of data.frames.

```
cbind(mtcars[1:4, 1:4], 
  list(data.frame(x1 = 1), data.frame(x2 = 2), data.frame(x3 = 3)))
```

**3)** create a chain of mutates (the result is a function) and use it with mtcars.

```
chain <- . %>% mutate(x1 = 1) %>% mutate(x2 = 2) %>% mutate(x3 = 3)
mtcars[1:4, 1:4] %>% chain
```

**4)** Use Reduce to repeatedly run `mutate`.  Replace `fun` with other suitable function for other applications.

```
fun <- function(x, i) mutate(x, setNames(data.frame(i), paste0("x", i)))
Reduce(fun, init = mtcars[1:4, 1:4], 1:3)
```

Comment: This is not the logic that I expect - I wanted a function that would `mtcars %>% mutate(x1=1) %>% mutate(x2=2) %>% mutate(x3=3) ...`, because if I want to apply functions within `mutate` I cannot see how to get this with your approach. Although I will test it out!

Comment: @joe_bill.dollar: That's why you need to tell us why you need to do this. Otherwise you're going to get answers that do what you ask for, not what you need.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: Nice, I didn't know that about `mutate`. Is it doing the same thing as `bind_cols` or `cbind` would do, though? That would seem a more intuitive verb.

Comment: Ah, you answered my question. :)

Comment: These are all interesting possibilities however the aim of the post was to produce n-series of dplyr-verbs, and I believe everyone has got the wrong impression. It was to be very generaliseable, such that any other method could be used other than `mutate` - I have updated my post.

Comment: I don't know why I'm always surprised by the "lazy" evaluation of `chain <- . %>% ...`.

Comment: Still not really clear on what the question is asking but have added a fourth approach just in case.

Answer (score 1):

```r
func <- function(x, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  for (ind in seq_along(dots)) {
    nm <- paste0("x", ind)
    x <- mutate(x, {{nm}} := dots[[ind]])
  }
  x
}
func(head(mtcars, 3), 1, 3)
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb x1 x2
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  1  3
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  1  3
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  1  3
```

Another option:

```r
func <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  data.frame(
    setNames(dots, paste0("x", seq_along(dots)))
  )
}
head(mtcars, 3) %>%
  mutate(func(1, 3))
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb x1 x2
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  1  3
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  1  3
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  1  3
```

Comment: Quick question, why will it not work if I wanted to mutate additional columns from the existing dataframe, i.e. ```func(head(mtcars, 3), vs, am)``` would say that `vs` not found? and how would I include this?

Comment: I didn't know you wanted to go that route.

Comment: Check my updated answer as it seems you all got the wrong impression

Comment: My second example (using `%>% mutate(func(...))` allows you do `mtcars %>% mutate(func(vs, am))`, did you try that?